# How to prevent the same ID row to display from Table1 if already exist in Table2? PHP

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I have two tables (Table1 and Table2). Table1 displays data on Page1 and Table2 displays data on Page2. My script sends a respective row and its ID from Table1 to Table2, when user clicks a button. So, I want to check and prevent from displaying the row from Table1 that already exist in Table2.

**The ID from Table1 is "inbox_id" and it goes to Table2 as a reference.**

Here is the **PHP** code

```
               $get_inbox = "select * from inbox";

           $run_inbox = mysqli_query($conn, $get_inbox);

           while($inbox_row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_inbox)){
               $inbox_id = $inbox_row['inbox_id'];
               $inbox_icon = $inbox_row['inbox_icon'];         
               $inbox_fullname = $inbox_row['inbox_fullname'];
               $inbox_email = $inbox_row['inbox_email'];
               $inbox_phone = $inbox_row['inbox_phone'];
               $inbox_subject = $inbox_row['inbox_subject'];
               $inbox_url = $inbox_row['inbox_url'];
               $inbox_message = $inbox_row['inbox_message'];
               $inbox_icon = $inbox_row['inbox_icon'];
               $inbox_day = $inbox_row['inbox_day'];    
               $inbox_date = $inbox_row['inbox_date'];
               $inbox_year = $inbox_row['inbox_year'];         
               $inbox_time = $inbox_row['inbox_time'];
               $inbox_timezone = $inbox_row['inbox_timezone'];

           {
```

Here is two screenshots of Table1 and Table2.

**Table1**
[image: Table1]

**Table2**
[image: Table2]

Answer (score 1):

Take your pick:

```
SELECT 
    inbox.* 
FROM 
    inbox 
    LEFT JOIN trash 
        ON inbox.inbox_id = trash.inbox_id
WHERE
    trash.trash_id IS NULL
```

---

```
SELECT
    inbox.*
FROM
    inbox
WHERE
    inbox_id NOT IN (
        SELECT inbox_id
        FROM trash
        WHERE 1 -- something here?
    )
```

---

```
SELECT
    inbox.*
FROM
    inbox
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM trash
        WHERE trash.inbox_id = inbox.inbox_id
    )
```

Some light reading to help you decide: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

Additionally, you might be able to save some space/effort, if you want all the fields coming back from the DB to live in variables of the same name, you can replace this:

```
    while($inbox_row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_inbox)){
           $inbox_id = $inbox_row['inbox_id'];
           $inbox_icon = $inbox_row['inbox_icon'];         
           $inbox_fullname = $inbox_row['inbox_fullname'];
           $inbox_email = $inbox_row['inbox_email'];
           $inbox_phone = $inbox_row['inbox_phone'];
           $inbox_subject = $inbox_row['inbox_subject'];
           $inbox_url = $inbox_row['inbox_url'];
           $inbox_message = $inbox_row['inbox_message'];
           $inbox_icon = $inbox_row['inbox_icon'];
           $inbox_day = $inbox_row['inbox_day'];    
           $inbox_date = $inbox_row['inbox_date'];
           $inbox_year = $inbox_row['inbox_year'];         
           $inbox_time = $inbox_row['inbox_time'];
           $inbox_timezone = $inbox_row['inbox_timezone'];

       {
```

with

```
    while($inbox_row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_inbox)){
           extract($run_inbox);

       {
```

See [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

Comment: I tried the first one and it gives me this error: Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\raincolordesign\admin\includes\inbox.php on line 31      this is how I check if there it finds a match in the database:       $run_inbox = mysqli_query($conn, $get_inbox1);   

   if(mysqli_num_rows($run_inbox) >0){
    
   }The other two, will not do anything.

Comment: My mistake in the first query was saying `inbox.id` not `inbox.inbox_id`; can you confirm that my assumptions about your tables otherwise match up?  I'm going to edit my answer to include this.  What happens when you run the query manually?

Answer (score 0):

When you draw table in the Table2, store the inbox_id as id of the table row. So when you want insert data in table2, use the inbox_id to check whether it exist using jquery and if not then add the row at the end of table.

Comment: That's correct. I have explained that in the question, that I stored the ID from Table1 and send it to Table2 as a reference. My question is how to select the ID from Table2 and check If exist in Table1? –

Answer (score 0):

```
As I gone through your question. I will request you to put screen sort of your Table Structure(Table 1, Table 2) with records of possible. So will easy for any one to answer your query. Looking forward to your response.  Try to execute this code in your page. I hope this will work. 


$get_inbox = "select * from inbox where inbox_id not in($clicked_id)";

$run_inbox = mysqli_query($conn, $get_inbox);
while ($inbox_row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_inbox)) {
    $inbox_id = $inbox_row['inbox_id'];
    $inbox_icon = $inbox_row['inbox_icon'];
    $inbox_fullname = $inbox_row['inbox_fullname'];
    $inbox_email = $inbox_row['inbox_email'];
    $inbox_phone = $inbox_row['inbox_phone'];
    $inbox_subject = $inbox_row['inbox_subject'];
    $inbox_url = $inbox_row['inbox_url'];
    $inbox_message = $inbox_row['inbox_message'];
    $inbox_day = $inbox_row['inbox_day'];
    $inbox_date = $inbox_row['inbox_date'];
    $inbox_year = $inbox_row['inbox_year'];
    $inbox_time = $inbox_row['inbox_time'];
    $inbox_timezone = $inbox_row['inbox_timezone'];

}
```

Comment: Just did. Hopefully that will help.